# SharePoint 2010 - Search Box Web Part and Search Results Page Customization

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Would someone be willing to offer me some assistance with customizing the search results page and the search box web part properties.

**First problem: Search Box Properties**

When I add an additional query term (eg. fileextension="xml") the search runs as expected but the refinement panel dissapears on the search results page. I don't want it to dissapear! I just want certain filters to be pre-applied.

**Second Problem: Search Results Page**

How do I customize the way results are displayed. For instance, I would like to add different refinement options to the refinement panel. I would also like to change what information is displayed under each individual result. Currently it seems to show a summary of the content, followed by the author and sometimes the date. I'd like to change this. How???

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The results part you need to update the XSLT, You can do this via one of the web part properties. You will also need to make sure that the fields you want to put in to the results are included in your columns(Also a web part property)

Check this out 
https://littletalk.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/customizing-search-core-result-xslt-in-sharepoint-2010/

Refinement options are based on Your crawled properties. Check this out

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/03/15/get-to-know-the-refinement-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-enterprise-search.aspx

Not sure as to why your refinement panel is disappearing, Check to see if the URL changes dramatically when you add your fileextension="xml" to the web part property, it may be that this addition is changing the URL so much the refinement panel is loaded or can't load but don't hold me to this

cheers to the

Truez